# CSS to align horizontal label and forms

Tags: html, css, mako

Within my Mako Template ,I display a list of existing "Options", and for each of them I have 5 forms with submit buttons. They are currently displayed like this :

```
.....
Option_i
  Buton_i_1
  Buton_i_2
  Buton_i_3
  Buton_i_4
  Buton_i_5
.....
```

I would like to have the arranged hoorizontally, like this

```
.....
Option_i Buton_i_1 Buton_i_1 Buton_i_1 Buton_i_1** 
.....
```

My current html code to generate an "Option"  looks like this :

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label class="header_option" >OPTION</label>
    </div>

<div>   
    <form name="input" action="action_1" method="get">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  <form name="input" action="action_2" method="get">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 .................
  <form name="input" action="action_5" method="get">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<div>
```

Any suggest towards achieving the desired effect ?

Comment: add: `float: left` to your `form` in your CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
    <div>
      <label class="header_option" >OPTION</label>
    </div>
    <div>   
      <form name="input" action="action_1" method="get">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <form name="input" action="action_2" method="get">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <form name="input" action="action_3" method="get">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <form name="input" action="action_4" method="get">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <form name="input" action="action_5" method="get">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { 
    float: left;
}
form {
    float: left;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/eBu29/

Also make some changes with your DIV's, you didn't closed them all etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try below `CSS`

```
form
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
div
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
```